# Printing Output Causes Split Lines Half of The Time

Tags: python

I am trying to automate a task which requires using a specific URL which changes depending on the site location. The site locations are already loaded into a .txt file with no spaces at the beginning nor end of each line. The script runs down the list and changes the variable in the URL to match the line it is currently on then saves it to a file to be used later.

The issue I am having is that the script seems to split the outputted lines nearly every time which breaks my ability to read the lines in the next program.

Sample output:

```
https://picklepickle.com/api/11/networks/12312313154564654  
/fickle/toast/3  
https://picklepickle.com/api/11/networks/12312313154564655  
/fickle/toast/3  
https://picklepickle.com/api/11/networks/12312313154564656/fickle/toast/3  
https://picklepickle.com/api/11/networks/12312313154564657/fickle/toast/3
```

This is a small snippet as the original file has nearly 100 lines in it.

Why does the code output the lines in such a weird way? How do I fix it so that it outputs each URL into one neat line?

```
raw = open("NetIDs.txt")

networks = raw.readlines()

for line in networks:
    for i in line:
        f = open("Checker.txt", "a+")
        f.write('https://picklepickle.com/api/11/networks/{}/fickle/toast/3\n'.format(line))
        f.close()
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: This is the entire code block other than the raw text file that the variables are pulled from. That text file is just a series of numbers on individual lines.

The expected output is each line containing the entire URL with the correct variable inserted.

Comment: What's the point of the `for i in line` loop?

Comment: "Why does the code output the lines in such a weird way?" Well, what's the *usual* reason that a string spans multiple lines? Because it has newline characters in it, right? Now, can you think of a reason why that might be happening? What happened when you *tried to check* whether that is the case? For example, when you tried to check the value of `line` being formatted into the output string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try stripping your raw text- `readlines()` will return `\n` (newline characters), as well.

```py
... 
f.write('https://picklepickle.com/api/11/networks/{}/fickle/toast/3\n'.format(line.strip()))
...
```

The `.strip()` will remove characters like `\n`,`\t`, and more.

Comment: Eyyyyyy. This worked like a charm.